# How best to backfill data with Google Cloud Workflows

Tags: google-workflows

I am getting up to speed on GCP Workflows. What is the best practice for handling backfilling data with Workflows, and are there any built in methods like airflow? If not, then it looks like the best option is to pass in a start_date and keep looping through a subworkflow while incrementing the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find how to backfile on the [official Google documentation on backfiling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#backfilling), though this does refer specifically to BigQuery... It's what makes the most sense within the context that you're mentioning, seeing as Workflows is more of a... job scheduler? I guess?

If this is not what you are referring to, then could you please clarify what it is that you are attempting to do with GCP Workflows?
I'm asking because by the definition of workflows found in the [overview for Google Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/overview#workflow_basics), they don't really have associated/built-in methods, they just call the methods that you program them to.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. I think you are right that there is nothing built-in to GCP Workflows for handling this, but since my data is going from Cloud Storage to BigQuery, I can use the BigQuery transfer service https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#manually_triggering_a_transfer

Comment: Oh, have you managed to do it this way? As in, used a manual transfer to backfill your data over? If so might I recommend posting it as an answer to your own question and accepting it? That way anyone who wants to do the same thing can easily see how you achieved it and see that it worked.

Comment: I am working on it, and that is a good suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so the solution is much warranted!